# c# timer and form1 hide or show

Tags: c#, forms, timer

There's one timer. Every 10 seconds will hide form1, then it will show form1 again. default form load show()
How can I do that ?

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        timer(); 
    }

    private void timer() {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = (10000); /
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Start();
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.theProcess);
    }
```

How do I fill this theProcess function

Comment: Fill in timers elapsed event handler

Comment: how ? This is already the answer to the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute _timer.start() after the handler is assigned.
code for this process

```
form1.Visible=!form1.Visible.
```